# How can I run Xamarin on Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, xamarin

When I tried to install Xamarin on my XP I'm getting fail message since it's impossible to install .Net framework version 4.5.

Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: This question should be asked on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a manual install of the Xamarin components:
http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/

Hope this helps!